# Good "progress bar" about md5sum checking progress?

Tags: shell, utilities, hashsum

I'm using this right now:

```
time md5sum -c *.txt | pv | grep -v ': OK$'
```

but aren't there any smart solutions that can list that how many files haven't been checked? I mean I have many md5sum's in .txt files in a dir, and I need to check them, but it would be a good thing to know that how much files are left to scan..

p.s.: so it's not really a progress bar, just a counter that output how many files are there left to "md5sum -c FILENAME"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the names to `md5sum` one by one.

```
n=$(cat *.txt | wc -l)
cat *.txt | {
  i=0 bad=0
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    i=$((i+1))
    echo "Checking file $i/$n: $line"
    echo "$line" | md5sum -c - || bad=$((bad+1))
  done
  [ $bad -eq 0 ] || { echo "$bad bad checksums"; false; }
}
```

Or, for casual use, you can run the simple command and check which file `md5sum` is up to by seeing what it has open.

```
lsof -p1234
# note the file name
cat *.txt | grep -n FILENAME
```

Comment: thanks, it's almost perfect :P i upgraded/downgraded it a little bit: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eqfiXzaB