# Using pv with md5sum

Tags: pipe, hashsum, pv

I used `md5sum` with `pv` to check 4 GiB of files that are in the same directory:

```
md5sum dir/* | pv -s 4g | sort
```

The command completes successfully in about 28 seconds, but `pv`'s output is all wrong. This is the sort of output that is displayed throughout:

```
219 B 0:00:07 [ 125 B/s ] [>                                ]  0% ETA 1668:01:09:02
```

It's like this without the `-s 4g` and `| sort` aswell. I've also tried it with different files.

I've tried using `pv` with `cat` and the output was fine, so the problem seems to be caused by `md5sum`.

Comment: It's likely a buffering issue. That is, the output from `md5sum` is not line-buffered and won't arrive at `pv` until the process is done or has produced enough data to fill the output buffer.  I can't see an option in the `md5sum` manual to make it line-buffered.  Or, you are misunderstanding what is happening, which is that the data sent through `pv` is only the checksums (and filenames).  Also `pv` does not know how much data to expect, so it can't say how much is left.

Comment: It seems like only the checksums and filenames are going thorough `pv` (but this doesn't seem to affect anyone else?). Is there are way to make all of the file data go through `pv`?

Comment: The issue with that is that you would loose the filename.  Think of `pv` as a "fancy `cat`".  Using `cat file | md5sum`, you would get the MD5 hash for a single file, but `md5sum` has no way of tagging the result with a filename.

Comment: You are using `pv` to rate the output of md5sum (which is a few bytes) and not `md5sum`'s own progress of reading the files themselves. Maybe this answer is related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16826/30851 (on second thought, maybe not - it's about textfiles...)

Comment: Since you are not feeding 4Gb of data down the pipe, but just the output of `md5sum` for a plurality of files, changing the `-s 4g` option such that it reflects an estimate of the size of `md5sum`'s output, e.g. `-s 512`, should be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `pv` utility is a "fancy `cat`", which means that you may use `pv` in most situations where you would use `cat`.

Using `cat` with `md5sum`, you can compute the MD5 checksum of a single file with

```
cat file | md5sum
```

or, with `pv`,

```
pv file | md5sum
```

Unfortunately though, this does not allow `md5sum` to insert the filename into its output properly.

Now, fortunately, `pv` is a *really* fancy `cat`, and on some systems (Linux), it's able to *watch* the data being passed through another process.  This is done by using its `-d` option with the process ID of that other process.

This means that you can do things like

```
md5sum dir/* | sort >sums &
sleep 1
pv -d "$(pgrep -n md5sum)"
```

This would allow `pv` to watch the `md5sum` process.  The `sleep` is there to allow `md5sum`, which is running in the background, to properly start.  `pgrep -n md5sum` would return the PID of the most recently started `md5sum` process that you own. `pv` will exit as soon as the process that it is watching terminates.

I've tested this particular way of running `pv` a few times and it seems to generally work well, but sometimes it seems to stop outputting anything as `md5sum` switches to the next file.  Sometimes, it seems to spawn spurious background tasks in the shell.

It would probably be safest to run it as

```
md5sum dir/* >sums &
sleep 1
pv -W -d "$!"
sort -o sums sums
```

The `-W` option will cause `pv` to wait until there's actual data being transferred, although this does also not always seem to work reliably.

Comment: The need for `sleep` is somewhat surprising!

Comment: @StephenKitt That's the only way I could get it to behave somewhat predictably.  I don't really know what it does, but whatever it is, it seems to be possible for it to do it "too early", and the progress meter won't show at all.

Answer (score 5):

The data that you are feeding through the pipe is not the data of the files that `md5sum` is processing, but instead the `md5sum` output, which, for every file, consists of one line comprising: the MD5-hash, two spaces, and the file name. Since we know this in advance, can inform `pv` accordingly, so as to enable it to display an accurate progress indicator. There are two ways of doing so.

The first, preferred method (suggested by frostschutz) makes use of the fact that `md5sum` generates one line per processed file, and the fact that `pv` has a line mode that counts lines rather than bytes. In this mode `pv` will only move the progress bar when it encounters a newline in the throughput, i.e. per file finished by `md5sum`. In Bash, this first method can look like this:

```
set -- *.iso; md5sum "$@" | pv --line-mode -s $# | sort
```

The `set` builtin is used to set the positional parameters to the files to be processed (the `*.iso` shell pattern is expanded by the shell). `md5sum` is then told to process these files (`$@` expands to the positional parameters), and `pv` in line mode will move the progress indicator each time a file has been processed / a line is output by `md5sum`. Notably, `pv` is informed of the total number of lines it can expect (`-s $#`), as the special shell parameter `$#` expands to the number of positional arguments.

The second method is not line-based but byte-based. With `md5sum` this unnecessarily complicated, but some other program may not produce lines but for instance continuous data, and then this approach may be more practical. I illustrate it with `md5sum` though. The idea is to calculate the amount of data that `md5sum` (or some other program) will produce, and use this to inform `pv`. In Bash, this could look as follows:

```
os=$(( $( ls -1 | wc -c ) + $( ls -1 | wc -l ) * 34 ))
md5sum * | pv -s $os | sort
```

The first line calculates the output size (`os`) estimate: the first term is the number of bytes necessary for encoding the filenames (incl. newline), the second term the number of bytes used for encoding the MD5-hashes (32 bytes each), plus 2 spaces. In the second line, we tell `pv` that the expected amount of data is `os` bytes, so that it can show an accurate progress indicator leading up to 100% (which indicator is updated per finished md5summed file).

Obviously, both methods are only practical in case multiple files are to be processed. Also, it should be noted that since the output of `md5sum` is not related to the amount of time the `md5sum` program has to spend crunching the underlying data, the progress indicator may be considered somewhat misleading. E.g., in the second method, the file with the shortest name will yield the lowest progress update, even though it may actually be the biggest in size. Then again, if all files have a similar sizes and names, this shouldn't matter much.

Comment: It's a very nice idea to calculate progress based on `md5sum` output (even though the progress would indicate how many files are still left, and not - how large or how long that would take). However it should not require parsing `ls`. `pv` supports `--line-mode` so `set -- *.iso; md5sum "$@" | pv --line-mode -s $# | sort` might be equivalent and still work if you replace md5sum with sha512sum or otherwise.

Comment: @frostschutz You are undeniably right :-) This is a nicer, cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dirty hack to get progress per file:

```
for f in iso/*
do
    pv "$f" | (
        cat > /dev/null &
        md5sum "$f"
        wait
    )
done
```

What it looks like:

```
4.15GiB 0:00:32 [ 130MiB/s] [================================>] 100%            
0db0b36fc7bad7b50835f68c369e854c  iso/KNOPPIX_V7.6.1DVD-2016-01-16-EN.iso
 792MiB 0:00:06 [ 130MiB/s] [================================>] 100%            
97537db63e61d20a5cb71d29145b2937  iso/archlinux-2016.10.01-dual.iso
 843MiB 0:00:06 [ 129MiB/s] [================================>] 100%            
1b5dc31e038499b8409f7d4d720e3eba  iso/lubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso
 259MiB 0:00:02 [ 130MiB/s] [=========>                        ] 30% ETA 0:00:04
...
```

Now, this makes several assumptions. Firstly, that reading data is slower than hashing it. Secondly, that OS will cache the I/O so data won't be (physically) read twice even though `pv` and `md5sum` are completely independent readers.

The nice thing about such a dirty, dirty hack is that you can easily adapt it to make a progress bar across all the data, not just one file. And still do weird stuff like sort the output afterwards.

```
pv iso/* | (
    cat > /dev/null &
    md5sum iso/* | sort
    wait
)
```

What it looks like (ongoing):

```
15.0GiB 0:01:47 [ 131MiB/s] [===========================>      ] 83% ETA 0:00:21
```

What it looks like (finished):

```
18.0GiB 0:02:11 [ 140MiB/s] [================================>] 100%            
0db0b36fc7bad7b50835f68c369e854c  iso/KNOPPIX_V7.6.1DVD-2016-01-16-EN.iso
155603390e65f2a8341328be3cb63875  iso/systemrescuecd-x86-4.2.0.iso
1b5dc31e038499b8409f7d4d720e3eba  iso/lubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso
1b6ed6ff8d399f53adadfafb20fb0d71  iso/systemrescuecd-x86-4.4.1.iso
25715326d7096c50f7ea126ac20eabfd  iso/openSUSE-13.2-KDE-Live-i686.iso
...
```

Now, that's for the hacks. Check other answers for proper solutions. ;-)

Comment: Reading the data would be required to hashing it, so hashing the data is almost certainly slower than just reading it. Also, you force reading the data twice for each file (once with `pv` and once with `md5sum`).

Comment: @Kusalananda ...and that's why I called it a hack! `pv < /dev/zero | md5sum` -> 637MiB/s on my machine. The ISO files I tested with were on a USB3 stick, 140MiB/s is about the max read speed. So md5sum can hash data faster than read it. Yes it reads data twice, but that's pedantic - thanks to OS caching, the USB stick still reads it only once; and running this hack is (in my case) not any slower than running md5sum by itself without progress bar.

Comment: ...and yes, it can go wrong. If you were to do this on a slow machine with a very fast storage medium, `pv` would run way ahead of `md5sum` and data would probably end up being read twice for real, or in any case, the progress bar would not be in sync with md5sum at all.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in comments and other answers:

1. You are piping into `pv` only `md5sum`'s output: checksums and file names; thus, `pv`'s progress bar is not able to show how much data `md5sum` is reading.
2. A size of 4 GB will be of course too much for that. Also, providing `pv` with the size of the file(s) you are piping into it (manually, with `-s`) is inconvenient.

Piping the content of your files into `pv` and then into `md5sum` will give you a progress bar, but file names would be lost.

This code is a not so elegant way to have both—a meaningful progress bar and file names with checksums:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for file in "$@"; do
    pv -- "$file" |
    md5sum |
    sed 's/-$//' |
    printf '%s%s\n' "$(cat -)" "$file"
done
```

The script is meant to be invoked as:

```sh
./script dir/*
```

You can of course declare it as a function, to avoid having to type its path to call it (or adding it to your `PATH`):

```sh
function pvsum () {
    for file in "$@"; do
        pv -- "$file" |
          md5sum |
          sed 's/-$//' |
          printf '%s%s\n' "$(cat -)" "$file"
    done
}
```

This way, the command `pvsum dir/* | sort` will be equivalent to your `md5sum dir/* | pv -s <size> | sort`.

Its output:

```
$ ./testscript testdir/*
4.00GiB 0:00:09 [ 446MiB/s] [==============================>] 100%            
9dab5f8add1f699bca108f99e5fa5342  testdir/file1
1.00GiB 0:00:02 [ 447MiB/s] [==============================>] 100%            
06a738a71e3fd3119922bdac259fe29a  testdir/file2
```

What it does:

- It loops over the given files and, for each:

  - Pipes the file from `pv` into `md5sum`, showing the default progress bar.
  - `sed` is used to remove the `-` printed by `md5sum` (which is reading from standard input); this also attempts to make the output suitable for being consumed by `md5sum -c` (thanks to [frostschutz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30851/frostschutz) for pointing out this out)<sup>1</sup>.
  - Prints the checksum followed by the file name on standard output.

About `sort`:

I'm not sure about your expected results, so I have just ignored it. Since `pv` writes its progress bar to standard error, piping everything into `sort` will detach `pv`'s output from `md5sum`'s output.
Anyway, you can just append  `| sort` after `done` in the code above and check if the result is fine to you.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that the output from the code shown above will not be suitable for `md5sum -c` if file names include newlines. Handling newlines is possible, but some versions of `md5sum` behave differently in this respect (see, for instance, answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/424628/315749)), making a general solution not easy (and out of the scope of this answer).

Assuming a recent version of `md5sum`, an attempt at solving this issue could be:

```sh
for file in "$@"; do
    pv -- "$file" |
    md5sum |
    sed 's/-$//' |
    printf '%s%s\n' "$(cat -)" "$file" |
    sed -n 'H; 1h; $!d; g; s/\\/\\\\/g; s/\n/\\n/g; t x; p; q; :x s/^/\\/; p;'
done
```

Where the only addition, the final `sed`, will:

- Put the whole input, checksum and name of the current file, in pattern space, since it may contain newlines: `H` appends a newline and current pattern space to the hold space; `1h` overrides previous `H`, only for the first line, doing the same but without appending a newline; `$!d` starts a new cycle if the current line is not the last one; `g` puts the content of the hold space in pattern space.
- Escape with a backslash (`\`) any backslash in the resulting pattern space.
- Replace with `\n` any newline in the resulting pattern space.
- Only if at least a backslash or newline has been replaced (`t x`: branch to label `x`), a backslash is added at the beginning of the checksum to signal `md5sum -c` that something has to be unescaped; otherwise just quit. In both cases, print (`p`) the pattern space to standard output just before quitting (the option `-n` disables auto-printing).

Answer (score 1):

### I have also enjoyed taming the 'fancy cat', `pv`, for `md5sum` :-)

- I think my shellscript is rather stable now
- There is a `usage` output, if you do not enter the pattern correctly.
- It works with wild cards, but does not recurse into subdirectories
- You can enter more than one pattern, for example `".* *"`
- There is a verbosity switch that turns on checking the md5sums `... OK`
- You can redirect the relevant output into a file; the process view output of `pv` will stay on the {screen/terminal window}
- There are two `pv` processes in a for loop, one global and one for each file, the global `pv` 'only counts the files', and the other one measures the speed and amount of data transferred
- ANSI escape sequences are used to keep the process view in a stable position

I use the name `md5summer`, make the shellscript executable and put it in a directory in PATH (my `~/bin` directory, you may prefer `/usr/local/bin`).

```
#!/bin/bash

# date      sign     comment
# 20190119  sudodus  created md5summer version 1.0

if [ "$1" == "-v" ]
then
 verbose=true
 shift
else
 verbose=false
fi
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
 echo "Usage:    $0  [-v]  <pattern>"
 echo "Example:  $0  '*.iso'      # notice the quotes"
 echo "          $0  -v  '*.iso'  # verbose"
 exit
fi
tmpstr=$(find $1 -maxdepth 0 -type f 2> /dev/null)
if [ "$tmpstr" == "" ]
then
 echo "No such file '$1'. Try another pattern!"
 exit
fi

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
tmpfil="$tmpdir/fil1"
tmpfi2="$tmpdir/fil2"
resetvid="\0033[0m"
prev2line="\0033[2F"
next2line="\0033[2E"

sln=1
cln=0
cnt=0
for i in $1
do
 if test -f "$i"
 then
  cln=$((cln+1))
  tmp=$(find -L "$i" -printf "%s")
  cnt=$((cnt+tmp))
 fi
done
echo "
                    number of files = $cln
                    total file size = $cnt B ~ $(($cnt/2**20)) MiB
"
for i in $1
do
 if test -f "$i"
 then
  tmpnam=$(echo -n "$i")
  tmpsum=$(< "$i" pv -ptrbs "$cnt" | md5sum)
  sleep 0.05
  echo "$sln" | pv -ls "$cln" > /dev/null
  sleep 0.05
  sln="$sln
$i"
  sleep 0.05
  printf "${tmpsum/\-}${tmpnam}\n" >> "$tmpfil"
  echo -ne "$prev2line" > /dev/stderr
 fi
done

sync
sleep 0.1
echo -ne "$next2line" > /dev/stderr

echo "-----"
if $verbose
then
 sort -k2 "$tmpfil" | tee "$tmpfi2" | md5sum -c
 echo "-----"
 cat "$tmpfi2"
else
 sort -k2 "$tmpfil"
fi
sleep 0.5
sync
rm -r "$tmpdir"
```

### Demo example

Usage

```
$ md5summer 
Usage:    /home/sudodus/bin/md5summer  [-v]  <pattern>
Example:  /home/sudodus/bin/md5summer  '*.iso'      # notice the quotes
          /home/sudodus/bin/md5summer  -v  '*.iso'  # verbose
```

I tested in this directory

```
$ ls -1a
.
..
'filename with spaces'
md5summer
md5summer1
md5summer2
subdir
.ttt
zenity-info-message.png
```

Normal usage plus pattern to see hidden files

```
$ md5summer ".* *"

                    number of files = 6
                    total file size = 12649 B ~ 0 MiB

8,32KiB 0:00:00 [ 156MiB/s] [=============================>                ] 67%
6,00  0:00:00 [ 133k/s] [====================================>] 100%            
-----
184d0995cc8b6d8070f89f15caee35ce  filename with spaces
28227139997996c7838f07cd4c630ffc  md5summer
3383b86a0753e486215280f0baf94399  md5summer1
28227139997996c7838f07cd4c630ffc  md5summer2
31cd03f64a466e680e9c22fef4bcf14b  .ttt
670b8db45e57723b5f1b8a63399cdfa1  zenity-info-message.png
```

Verbose output plus pattern to see hidden files

```
$ md5summer -v ".* *"

                    number of files = 6
                    total file size = 12649 B ~ 0 MiB

8,32KiB 0:00:00 [ 184MiB/s] [=============================>                ] 67%
6,00  0:00:00 [ 133k/s] [====================================>] 100%            
-----
filename with spaces: OK
md5summer: OK
md5summer1: OK
md5summer2: OK
.ttt: OK
zenity-info-message.png: OK
-----
184d0995cc8b6d8070f89f15caee35ce  filename with spaces
28227139997996c7838f07cd4c630ffc  md5summer
3383b86a0753e486215280f0baf94399  md5summer1
28227139997996c7838f07cd4c630ffc  md5summer2
31cd03f64a466e680e9c22fef4bcf14b  .ttt
670b8db45e57723b5f1b8a63399cdfa1  zenity-info-message.png
```

Redirection to a file, first the screen output

```
$ md5summer ".* *" > subdir/save
8,32KiB 0:00:00 [ 180MiB/s] [=============================>                ] 67%
6,00  0:00:00 [ 162k/s] [====================================>] 100%
```

and then the saved output

```
$ cat subdir/save 

                    number of files = 6
                    total file size = 12649 B ~ 0 MiB

-----
184d0995cc8b6d8070f89f15caee35ce  filename with spaces
28227139997996c7838f07cd4c630ffc  md5summer
3383b86a0753e486215280f0baf94399  md5summer1
28227139997996c7838f07cd4c630ffc  md5summer2
31cd03f64a466e680e9c22fef4bcf14b  .ttt
670b8db45e57723b5f1b8a63399cdfa1  zenity-info-message.png
```

Checking iso files

```
$ md5summer "*.iso"

                    number of files = 10
                    total file size = 7112491008 B ~ 6783 MiB

28,0MiB 0:00:00 [ 160MiB/s] [>                                             ]  0%
10,0  0:00:00 [ 204k/s] [====================================>] 100%            
-----
7a27fdd46a63ba4375896891826c1c88  debian-live-8.6.0-amd64-lxde-desktop.iso
d70eec28cdbdee7f7aa95fb53b9bfdac  debian-live-8.7.1-amd64-standard.iso
382cfbe621ca446d12871b8945b50d20  debian-live-8.8.0-amd64-standard.iso
44473dfe2ee1aad0f71506f1d5862457  debian-live-8.8.0-i386-standard.iso
f396b3532fa84059e7738c3c1827bada  debian-live-9.3.0-amd64-cinnamon.iso
8f6def28ae7cbefa0a6e59407c884466  debian-live-9.6.0-amd64-cinnamon.iso
90b1815da0a5bf4ee4b00eec2b5d3587  debian-testing-amd64-netinst_2017-07-28.iso
8f75074ab98e166b7469299d3e459ac6  mini-amd64-2016-01-21-daily.iso
e580266fba58eb34b05bf6e13f51a047  mini-jessie-32.iso
646c109a9a16c0527ce1c7afa922e2ed  mini-jessie-64.iso
```