# Is there a command that combines `tee` and `grep` such that in a pipeline the tee part can direct matches to a file?

Tags: grep, tail, tee

I'm looking to pull multiple pieces from a file, or at least watch for pieces in a log file if they should occur, but I don't want to setup multiple `tail | grep` sessions.  Instead I'd like to just tail the output of each grep.

I suppose I could do this with `awk`, but perhaps there is something closer to this idea already.

For example the command might look something like this:

```bsh
tail -f /var/log/syslog | teegrep cron1 -f CRON | teegrep cloud-init2 -f CLOUD-INIT
```

The output would be the files CRON and CLOUD-INIT, while all things would go to stdout by the end.  Only the matches for 'cron1' and 'cloud-init2' lines would wind up in their respective files.

Maybe it's already part of a command and I have just not known about it.  Or possibly just some bash/zsh trickery that would do the same thing. 
 Either way:  Is there a command that combines `tee` and `grep` such that in a pipeline the tee part can direct matches to a file?

Comment: Possibly `tail -f /var/log/syslog | pee 'grep cron1 > CRON' 'grep cloud-init2 > CLOUD-INIT'` ? See ['tee' for commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371730/65304)

Comment: Perhaps you ask for something similar I questioned some month ago [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522914/can-i-duplicate-output-of-a-pipe)

Comment: "I don't want to setup multiple `tail | grep`" That needs some rationale. A `teegrep` as you describe (which could be implemented with process substitutions as in @Kusalananda's answer or with an awk script), whould not use less resources. If anything, it will be slower, because the `tail | grep`s will run separately, without having to wait for each other as the "teegrep"s in a single pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a shell with process substitutions, `>(...)`:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | 
tee >(grep cron1 >CRON) | 
tee >(grep cloud-init2 >CLOUD-INIT)
```

This would cause `tail` to produce data for the first `tee` in the pipeline.  The `tee` would duplicate the data and send one copy across to the next `tee` and the other into a process substitution.  That process substitution would run `grep` on the data arriving from `tee` and the result would go to the file `CRON`.

The last stage of the pipeline would work in a similar way.

---

In a shell where process substitutions are not available, e.g. `/bin/sh`, `awk` or `sed` could be used.

With `awk`:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | 
awk '{ print }
     /cron1/       { print >"CRON" }
     /cloud-print/ { print >"CLOUD-INIT" }'
```

With `sed` (note that we have to make sure that the output files don't exist, since the `w` command in `sed` always appends data to a file):

```
rm -f CLOUD CLOUD-INIT

tail -f /var/log/syslog | 
sed -e '/cloud/w CLOUD' \
    -e '/cloud-print/w CLOUD-INIT'
```